# HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Please I need help with this ASP.NET MVC 5 error in my code

The string parameter for viewing user details seems not to be available to the method even when it is there in the url and so the method returns a 
**HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request**

Here is my RouteConfig.cs

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Residents",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Residents", action = "Details", id ="UserId"}
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

And this is the method:

```
     // GET: Residents/Details/5
    //[ActionName("Resident-details")]
    public ActionResult Details(string username)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

      ApplicationUser user = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
        ViewBag.user = user;

        return View();
    }
```

This is the resulting url

http://localhost:59686/Residents/Details/8b422e1d-12cf-42c2-8606-32123b3dc577

but it returns a bad request.
Even when I do 
    return Content(username)
early in the method, it returns nothing. Nothing is displayed indicating that the parameter is not visible to the method.

Please I will appreciate a solution to this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route configuration is incorrect. Your method does not have parameter named `id`, but you are still defining it in your route configuration.

In order to fix the issue change your Residents route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
       name: "Residents",
       // only apply route to Residents/Details/your-user-name
       // make sure to use parameter name {username}, like in your method
       url: "Residents/Details/{username}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Residents", action = "Details"}
```

Comment: Arrrrrrrrrrh! Thank you so much @dotnetom. That fixed it for me. I am grateful

Answer (score 0):

So default model binding of MVC expects an int parameter to map your url to action method parameters.

alternatively you can use following url:
http://host/Controller/Details?username=8b422e1d-12cf-42c2-8606-32123b3dc577

or another option is try submitting data using POST method which will contain the username value.